# Translation of "Let me think about it"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

If my friend asks me to make a decision and I want to say "Let me think about it", should it be

> Lass mich darüber zu denken.

?

I'm not sure if this is a complete sentence, and if we need a comma after "mich".

Also, would "let me take some time to think about it" be

> Lass mich etwas Zeit, darüber zu denken

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite correct and the two correct translations are:

> Lass mich darüber nachdenken.

or

> Gib/Lass mir etwas Zeit, um darüber nachzudenken.

Some points

1. `Nachdenken` is here more suitable then `denken`. The latter is a
   general word for `to think`, the former means specifically `think
   about something`.
2. After `lass` there is always an infinitive without `zu`.
3. In the second sentence there is of course `mir` (Dativ) instead of `mich` (Akkusativ).

### Edit

As pointed out by Em1 (thanks), in my second example there is a verb `lassen` followed by `infinitive + zu` which seems to contradict the point 2 above. The reason is that in this case I am using a `um...zu + infinitive` construction which must contain `zu`. I think in this respect the use of `lassen` is very similar to the english `let`:

> Lass mich nachdenken - Let me think
>
> Lass mir Zeit, **um** nach***zu***denken - Let me take some time, **to** think about it.

Comment: The _um_ is optional in the second sentence.

Comment: Regarding the edit: It’s two different uses of _lassen_. The first is the modal verb, taking an infitive without _zu_. The second is a normal verb that doesn’t accept an infitive at all. The phrase _(um) darüber nachzudenken_ depends on _Zeit_.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also say

> Gib mir Zeit zum Nachdenken.